# How to show reasoning/basis for a classification/prediction in Weka

Tags: weka

I am using Weka Java API for training a model and making predictions. I am able to build a classifier based on 3 algorithms: Decision Trees, Naïve Bayes and Random Forest. Then able to classify a test instance and get a probability distribution over the target classes.

My question is – how do I show the reasoning/basis [consumable result, easily understandable] for the prediction. Why a given instance was classified as ‘A’, ‘B’ or ‘C’. Since the end-user would also like to know the logic behind the classification.